# PHPMYADMIN SQL Not Like Including Multiple Values

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm attempting to make a search query on my PHPMYADMIN database for users' emails that do not contain multiple NOT LIKE values. I want to search for users that do not have accounts at certain educational institutions.
i.e. search for users whose emails do not include schoola.edu schoolb.edu or schoolc.edu.

I believe it's similar to NOT LIKE %schoola.edu%, %schoolb.edu%, %schoolc.edu% or the like. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks so much for your suggestions. I found the solution:

SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (`email` NOT LIKE '%schoola.edu%') AND (`email` NOT LIKE '%schoolb.edu%').

The important distinction to make here is that %schoola.edu% is surrounded by apostrophes not back quotes as ***email*** is.

For people who are coming here for their own problems:

**Email** here acts as a column within the table **user** and **schoola.edu** and **schoolb.edu** are the contents of the email addresses that I do not want to include. So, **schoola.edu and schoolb.edu** are just components of the full email addresses thus the % signs. With this, I am returned with values of users who do not attend schoola.edu or schoolb.edu just as I want.

Here's a screenshot for clarification:[image: PhpMyAdmin]

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `NOT LIKE %schoola.edu% AND NOT LIKE %schoolb.edu% AND NOT LIKE %schoolc.edu%`

Comment: @cpburnz
So i tried this: SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 1 `email` NOT LIKE '%schoola.edu%' AND `email` NOT LIKE '%schoolb.edu%' and it's not functioning right. user is the table and email is the column.

Comment: @stvhuh Perhaps you could add a sample set of your data to your question, show your expected results, and the actual (incorrect) results you're receiving.